# making an angry bird look alike on unity. found a bug and still cant fix it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

while dragging my mouse i could extend the bird enough to kill the enemies and destroy the crates. is there any way to limit the extension or to fix the bug and stop the bird from colliding with other elements before mouse button is up?

```
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = true;

    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        Vector2 directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * _launchPower);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 1;
        _birdWasLaunched = true;
        GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = false;

    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new `enter code here`Vector3 (newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
    }  
}
```

Comment: The bird position would be (newPosition - startPosition).normalized * Mathf.Clamp(Vector3.Distance(newPosition, startPosition), 0, maxDistance). StartPosition is the slingshot position.

Comment: In `OnMouseDown` disable the colliders on the bird?

Comment: nop it doesnt can u help me?